# Flickering image when using invalidate & update

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm learning VB.net. Many things I really don't know, yet.
I have been searching everywhere, and I can't find a solution for my problem.

I have two Forms in my program.
In the first one, I ask the user for data input, and I also make some calculations.
These results are then passed to a second form, in which I draw lines.

[This is the initial form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByV9x.png)

[This is the second form. This one displays the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyRBy.png)

Depending on the data that the user introduces into the first Form, I would like to see the resulting changes in the second one; this works with sending the data from the first to the second one...
The problem with the graphics is that it keeps the first initial value, and won't change again (I don't like this)

[image: Initial values, the graphics are doing ok]

[I am changing the values, but the graphics won't reset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4VDn.png)

Searching through many different posts I put invalidate() and update(), and the graphics on the second form are finally updating. The problem is that there is a lots of flickering:
[Video of the program flickering](https://youtu.be/MuRBHnhk0kc)

This is the Form that has the problem... although... I don't know if this problem can be solved by asking `Form1` to do the drawing in the second Form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Diam_Barr As Double
    Dim Dist_Prim As Double
    Dim Dist_Seg As Double
    Dim Sag_Rin As Double
    Dim Sag_Cara As Double
    Dim Rin_3 As Double
    Dim Rin_9 As Double
    Dim Rin_6 As Double
    Dim Cara_3 As Double
    Dim Cara_6 As Double
    Dim Cara_9 As Double
    Dim NewCara_9 As Double
    Dim NewRin_9 As Double
    Dim Y0 As Double
    Dim Y1 As Double
    Dim Y2 As Double
    Dim Z0 As Double
    Dim Z1 As Double
    Dim Z2 As Double
    Dim m_Y As Double
    Dim m_Z As Double
    Dim SecondForm As New Form3

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Diam_Barr = DiamBarr.Text
        Dist_Prim = DistPrim.Text
        Dist_Seg = DistSeg.Text
        Sag_Rin = SagRin.Text
        Sag_Cara = SagCara.Text
        Cara_3 = Cara3.Text
        Cara_9 = Cara9.Text
        Rin_3 = Rin3.Text
        Rin_9 = Rin9.Text

        Cara_6 = Cara_3 + Cara_9
        Rin_6 = Rin_3 + Rin_9
        Cara6.Text = Cara_6
        Rin6.Text = Rin_6
        Y0 = (Rin_6 - Sag_Rin) / 2
        m_Y = (Cara_6 - Sag_Cara) / -Diam_Barr

        NewCara_9 = Cara_9 - Cara_3
        NewRin_9 = Rin_9 - Rin_3

        Z0 = NewRin_9 / 2
        m_Z = -NewCara_9 / Diam_Barr

        Y1 = (m_Y * Dist_Prim) + Y0
        Y2 = (m_Y * Dist_Seg) + Y0
        Z1 = (m_Z * Dist_Prim) + Z0
        Z2 = (m_Z * Dist_Seg) + Z0

        'Declarando la nueva forma y pasándole valores, también se redondean los mismos para que quepan en las cajitas de texto

        SecondForm.PendY.Text = Math.Round(m_Y, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        SecondForm.PendZ.Text = Math.Round(m_Z, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

        SecondForm.PtY0.Text = Math.Round(Y0, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        SecondForm.PtY1.Text = Math.Round(Y1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        SecondForm.PtY2.Text = Math.Round(Y2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

        SecondForm.PtZ0.Text = Math.Round(Z0, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        SecondForm.PtZ1.Text = Math.Round(Z1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
        SecondForm.PtZ2.Text = Math.Round(Z2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

        SecondForm.PtX2.Text = Math.Round(Dist_Seg, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

        SecondForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the second Form:

```
Public Class Form3
    'Omitimos el evento de load y lo cambiamos por el evento de pintar
    'Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Private Sub Form3_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint

        'Sacamos coordenadas para dibujar unas cajitas
        Dim PtA1 As New Point(245, 23)
        Dim PtA2 As New Point(673, 23)
        Dim PtA3 As New Point(673, 142)
        Dim PtA4 As New Point(245, 142)

        Dim PtB1 As New Point(245, 166)
        Dim PtB2 As New Point(673, 166)
        Dim PtB3 As New Point(673, 285)
        Dim PtB4 As New Point(245, 285)

        'puntos para dibujar las pendiente simuladas (para vertical)
        Dim PtCmax As New Point(250, 28)
        Dim PtCmin As New Point(250, 137)
        Dim PtCmed As New Point(250, 82.5)
        Dim PtDmax As New Point(673, 28)
        Dim PtDmin As New Point(673, 137)
        Dim PtDmed As New Point(673, 82.5)

        'puntos para dibujar las pendiente simuladas (para horizontal)
        Dim PtEmax As New Point(250, 171)
        Dim PtEmin As New Point(250, 280)
        Dim PtEmed As New Point(250, 225.5)
        Dim PtFmax As New Point(673, 171)
        Dim PtFmin As New Point(673, 280)
        Dim PtFmed As New Point(673, 225.5)

        'Dibujando los marcos
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtA1, PtA2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtA2, PtA3)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtA3, PtA4)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtA4, PtA1)

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtB1, PtB2)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtB2, PtB3)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtB3, PtB4)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, PtB4, PtB1)

        Dim Pend_Y As Double
        Dim Pend_Z As Double

        Pend_Y = Convert.ToDouble(PendY.Text)
        Pend_Z = Convert.ToDouble(PendZ.Text)

        Invalidate()
        Update()

        If Pend_Y < 0 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, PtCmax, PtDmin)
        ElseIf Pend_Y > 0 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, PtCmin, PtDmax)
        ElseIf Pend_Y = 0 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, PtCmed, PtDmed)
        End If

        If Pend_Z < 0 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, PtEmax, PtFmin)
        ElseIf Pend_Z > 0 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, PtEmin, PtFmax)
        ElseIf Pend_Z = 0 Then
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, PtEmed, PtFmed)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are calling Invalidate() **and** Update() inside the Paint event of a control. Both the Invalidate and Update calls have the direct consequence to raise the Paint event, over an over again, until you're app crashes. Don't do that. Test it also setting the `DoubleBuffered` property of the form to `True`.

Comment: where should I call them instead?

Comment: You call `Invalidate()`, **alone**, from a `Button.Click` event handler, for example, when you want to redraw your lines, e.g., when you have modified the data and you want to draw new lines. Or to add new shapes to those already existing. I hope all those `Dim PtA1` are there just for testing. You, of course, need a `List(Of PointF)`, declared outside the Paint event, that will hold the points references.

Comment: So... If I understand correctly, adding a button on the second form and just calling invalidate() would do the trick? List(Of PointF) are, I'm guessing here, listing all the points?

Comment: Yes! Adding a button with Invalidate() does the trick. Thanks!  I am going to work on it, so the deed is done in full auto... question... I also tried to invalidate directly from my initial form, but it was not doing a thing. Do you know if I can invalidate through this initial form?

Comment: + You need to call Invalidate() when you change something in the drawings. For example, if you keep your second Form as it is now, will all those `Dim PtA1, Dim PtA2 (...)`, when you open the Form, you'll see the drawing on the Form's surface. Now, if you want to draw something else, what can you do, since all the data is already hard-code inside the Paint event? Nothing.

Comment: You need to define those Points references somewhere else, add the data (in this case) to a `List(Of PointF)` and use this List reference inside the Paint event to draw the data Points. When you change the data in the List, the drawing will change accordingly. To trigger the re-paint of a control (in this case, because you want to draw the Points in the LIst that you have: Added, Removed, Modified), you call **`Invalidate()`**. This will repaint the control immediately, because `Invalidate()` raises the Paint event.

Comment: About the second question: yes, you can call Invalidate() from the first Form, it's common practice. But this can require many more comments, so you, maybe, make some tests, search `SO` about modifying a property of a Form from another Form or call a method of a Form from another Form (you'll find thousands) and if there's something that comes out badly twisted, make another question :)

Comment: Thanks Jimi, I think the best option would be to call invalidate as soon as I'm pressing the calculate button on the first form. I'll search for it.

Comment: I may be way off base here but there is a Chart Control in Visual Studio. It seems to draw beautiful line based on a Series of points. Might be worth a glance.

Comment: @Mary  Welll, that's the almost mandatory next step. A Chart control will greatly simplify the presentation of the Data. But learning how the Windows Forms handle the painting of their surfaces is also a good thing to know (and practice).

Comment: @Mary, I will look into the Chart Control, thanks for pointing it out. @Jimi, I see that you edited my post, thank you very much, and the solution was really easy, In my first form, if I add as a subfunction: `Private Sub Button_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.SecondForm.Invalidate()
    End Sub` then it works excellent. Thanks for the help and the tips. :-)